# Function COUNTIFS in POWER BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following formula in Excel

```
COUNTIFS(A1:A200,B1,C1:C200,"<="&D1), 

B1= StepTable
D1= 0.2
```

[image]

I need the total of each one of the data in the column `Step Table` that has `Hour <= 0.2`.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: use `SUMIF()` instead of `COUNTIF()`

Answer (score 0):

This will create a measure you can use in visuals:

```
Measure :=
CALCULATE ( COUNT ( 'Table'[Step Table] ), 'Table'[HoursData] <= 0.2 )
```

This you can use to create a new calculated column:

```
New Column :=
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( 'Table'[Step Table] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table' ),
            'Table'[Step Table] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Step Table] )
                && 'Table'[HoursData] < 0.25
        )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your prompt answer but it is not correct, i have tried a lot formulas but any works. the idea is that sum the step according to the condition:
example: for Input will be 3 less than or equal to 0.25..and so for each type of step. and that the measure use it next to the colum step and show me the value next to it.

Comment: So you need a calculated column, next to your 'StepTable' column that has the total count, for each 'StepTable' record less than .25... so in this case you would have a 4 beside "Input", a 1 beside "Repair" and a 1 for "Error" for every record?

Comment: @julianvesga please see the edit to my solution I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: OK. My report have columna STEP, Column #Transaction,Column HoursData. for each STEP there various Transaction (aprox 5,000) therefore  the STEP therefore one step can be repeated several times. and addition aech Transach have a time of process that is the column HourData.

Comment: COUNTIFS($A$19:$A$600000,$AJ20,$J$19:$J$600000,"<="&AZ$14)...EXPLANATION.........$A$19:$A$600000 =COLUMN STEP......  $AJ20 = TIPO STEP "INPUT.....  $J$19:$J$600000=COLUMN HOURS.......  "<="&AZ$14= CONDITION THAT IS <=0.25.